Edit queue seems permanently blocked
Many Ask Ubuntu posts are in dire need of editing for basic grammar and clarity. I have the time and the ability to do just that for free. Yet for some reason there is a limit to the daily edits. Why? And who exactly is qualified to review my edits for approval?
I used to teach English before I retired. I am now convinced that somebody is deliberately keeping the my edit queue blocked for reasons better known to them.
I want a moderator to look into this and name and shame those who abuse their privilege.

Well, I had a look at your case and I can confirm that there is nothing untoward in what has occurred in your case. Terdon's answer spells out the reasons and common practice on this site perfectly...

Regarding your last paragraph, that's not how we do things. Even if someone was abusing their edit privileges, the solution isn't to shame them on Meta. Mods generally will resolve issues like abuse of privileges with a user directly. There can be exceptions once in a while where someone's conduct is discussed via Meta, but even then, shaming isn't how we approach that. See https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/

The issue is also that the suggested edit queue has a fixed size (40 edits, plus possibly some at the edit form stage), and right now no one (needs 2k rep) is reviewing those edits.

Woah there. Please don't start by throwing accusations around. Yes, there are limits to the number of edits new (in terms of reputation) users can suggest. This is to prevent abuse. The ability to freely edit posts is something that can easily be taken advantage of by spammers to insert their spam or just general bad apples who enjoy adding pornography or other unwelcome things to posts. Once a user has reached 2000 reputation, they can edit freely, but until then, it takes the approval of two other users with at least that much reputation to accept an edit. None of this is about you, personally, it is just one of the many safeguards in place that are designed to allow a collaborative site like this one to function without becoming a cesspit.
You can find more information on this subject and who reviews your suggestions in our Help Center, on the  "editing" page:

Who makes sure that proposed edits are good?
Any user can propose edits, but not all edits are publicly visible immediately. If a user has less than 2,000 reputation, the suggested edit is placed in a review queue. Two accept or reject votes are required to remove the suggested edit from the queue and either apply the edit to the post or discard it.
Users with more than 2,000 reputation are considered trusted community members, and can edit posts without going through the review process. The original author of a question or answer may always edit their own post, regardless of reputation level.

In addition, and again with the aim of preventing abuse by bad players, each user can only have up to five pending suggested edits. You can find the details on this in the very comprehensive "Complete Rate Limiting Guide" post on the main Meta site, which has this to say on the subject (and yes, we do know that our system and documentation are both arcane and hard to find, spread out as they are over multiple locations; this is indeed a problem):


At most 5 pending suggested edits per editor (20 on beta sites)

Limit is partially waived if submitting a tag wiki and excerpt suggested edit at the same time (which counts as two edits) - if the user only has space for one more pending edit, both edits will still be allowed, but they cannot submit another suggested edit until two of their pending edits are approved (i.e. they're no longer exceeding the limit)




Looking at the suggested edit list of your profile (go to "All actions" and then click on "Suggestions"), I found some of your pending suggestions and I approved them (as a user with >2k reputation, I can do so), so you can now make more of the same type of helpful edit.
It's great that you want to take the time to make this kind of improvement and it is very appreciated. Give it a bit more time (you get a small amount of rep points per accepted edit suggestion), or post some questions or answers, and you will soon have enough reputation to edit directly without being limited in this way. However, do note that nobody is blocking you, none of this is personal, and everything seems to be working exactly as intended.
